# Mobile pull to refresh

Tags: iphone, html, jquery-mobile, uiscrollview, cordova

I use the phonegap jquery-mobile `isCrollView` to pull to refresh the view, but there is a problem that on the website that's ok but on the mobile when I pull down to refresh the header scroll with the view.